# Перевод описания пункта "Рекомендовать удаление" в "Запоздалых ответах"

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок, запоздалые-ответы

1. Переходим в очередь проверок "Запоздалые ответы"
2. В панели справа смотрим на пункт "Рекомендовать удаление"

В данном пункте отсутствует описание

> Answer does not address the question, is a duplicate, or cannot be improved.

**Скриншот:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Добавил вариант перевода:

> Answer does not address the question, is a duplicate, or cannot be improved.
> Не отвечает на заданный вопрос, является дубликатом или не может быть улучшен.
> https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16752

предложение было добавлено с учетом переводов других пунктов:
см. пример:

> **Выглядит нормально**
> Отвечает на заданный вопрос и не является ...
> **Рекомендовать удаление**
> Не отвечает на заданный вопрос, является ...

**Ожидаем подтверждение перевода.**

Comment: Утверждено уже какое-то время.